convert PDF file data to dataframe in python?
Is there a way to convert below pdf files data to dataframe ?
https://www.onrr.gov/document/2018.pdf
https://www.onrr.gov/document/2021.pdf

I have used 'tabula-py' to convert above pdfs to dataframe. But I get NaN in the rows for blank spaces.
https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/
Any help would be appreciated.

PDF is somewhat garbled due to the format and layout of the document..one appraoch you can try is converting pdf to image and then extract information may work..

You could try using libraries like https://weasyprint.org/ for more customised and advanced extractions
