remove NANs and create value field as a row?
I have a dataframe like below -
 |Business Name|Case Number|Violation|Regulation(s)|Payments|
0|NaN|NaN|NaN|30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR |NaN|
1|NaN|NaN|Business knowingly or willfully|Part 1218,Subparts B, D, E and|NaN|
2|CHI OPERATING CO|CP17‐085|sales months January 2011|30 CFR 1241.50‐52|$142,310|
3|NaN|NaN|Business failed to report production|30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C|NaN|
4|CROWHEARTENERGYLLC|CP19‐050|Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production|30CFR1241.50‐52|$5,544|
5|NaN|NaN|Business failed to submit Reports of Sale|NaN|NaN|
6|CHIZUM OIL LLC|CP20‐005|March 2018 through August 2018.|1241.50‐5|$7,497|
7|NaN|NaN|ONRR‐4054) for production months February 2009|NaN|NaN|
8|CHIZUM OIL LLC|CP19‐049|through November 2018. 1241.50‐52|NaN   |$3,421|


Can we  apply a check on Business Name if NaN then keep it as blank and don't count that as a row and whenever a value comes keep that as a row and combine all the values from above rows to that row.
Expected output -
 |Business Name|Case Number|Violation|Regulation(s)|Payments|
0|CHI OPERATING CO|CP17‐085|Business knowingly or willfully sales months January 2011|30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR Part 1218,Subparts B, D, E and 30 CFR 1241.50‐52|$142,310|
1|CROWHEARTENERGYLLC|CP19‐050|Business failed to report production Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production|30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52|$5,544|
2|CHIZUM OIL LLC|CP20‐005|Business failed to submit Reports of Sale March 2018 through August 2018.|1241.50‐5|$7,497|
3|CHIZUM OIL LLC|CP19‐049|ONRR‐4054) for production months February 2009 through November 2018. 1241.50‐52|NaN   |$3,421|



Use Series.bfill for back filling missing values for groups an aggregate custom lambda function with join and removing missing values:
out = (df.groupby(df.pop('Business Name').bfill())
         .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
         .reset_index())
print (out)
        Business Name Case Number                                          Violation                                      Regulation(s)  Payments Unnamed: 6
0    CHI OPERATING CO    CP17‐085  Business knowingly or willfully sales months J...  30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR  Part 1218,Subpart...  $142,310           
1  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Business failed to report production Reports(F...        30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544   

Solution should be changed if need combine each non missing value separately (rows 3,4 and rows 5,6):
print (df)
        Business Name Case Number                                Violation                   Regulation(s)  Payments 
        
0                 NaN         NaN                                      NaN    30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR        NaN 
1                 NaN         NaN          Business knowingly or willfully  Part 1218,Subparts B, D, E and       NaN
2    CHI OPERATING CO    CP17‐085                sales months January 2011               30 CFR 1241.50‐52  $142,310
3                 NaN         NaN     Business failed to report production     30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C       NaN         
4  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production                 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544
5                 NaN         NaN     Business failed to report production     30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C       NaN 
6  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production                 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544


out = (df.groupby(df['Business Name'].notna().iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1], sort=False)
          .agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
          .reset_index(drop=True))


print (out)
        Business Name Case Number                                          Violation                                      Regulation(s)  Payments Unnamed: 6
0    CHI OPERATING CO    CP17‐085  Business knowingly or willfully sales months J...  30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR  Part 1218,Subpart...  $142,310           
1  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Business failed to report production Reports(F...        30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544           
2  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Business failed to report production Reports(F...        30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544    

If in real data is combination strings and numeric columns is possible use:
print (df)
        Business Name Case Number                                Violation                   Regulation(s)  Payments  col
                                                                                                                         
0                 NaN         NaN                                      NaN    30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR        NaN    4
1                 NaN         NaN          Business knowingly or willfully  Part 1218,Subparts B, D, E and       NaN    1
2    CHI OPERATING CO    CP17‐085                sales months January 2011               30 CFR 1241.50‐52  $142,310    0
3                 NaN         NaN     Business failed to report production     30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C       NaN    1
4  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production                 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544    7
5                 NaN         NaN     Business failed to report production     30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C       NaN    1
6  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Reports(Forms ONRR‐4054)for22production                 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544    2


out = (df.groupby(df['Business Name'].notna().iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1], sort=False)
          .agg(lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else ' '.join(x.dropna()))
          .reset_index(drop=True))


print (out)
        Business Name Case Number                                          Violation                                      Regulation(s)  Payments  col
0    CHI OPERATING CO    CP17‐085  Business knowingly or willfully sales months J...  30 CFR 1241.60(b)(1) 30 CFR  Part 1218,Subpart...  $142,310    5
1  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Business failed to report production Reports(F...        30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544    8
2  CROWHEARTENERGYLLC    CP19‐050  Business failed to report production Reports(F...        30 CFR Part 1210, Subpart C 30CFR1241.50‐52    $5,544    3


is it possible to process this type of PDF - https://www.onrr.gov/document/2021.pdf and https://www.onrr.gov/document/2018.pdf ? I have used tabula-py library to convert this pdf to dataframe like this tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_url, pages=0) ,df = [table for table in tables] , also raised question on stack overflow -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78870815/convert-pdf-file-data-to-dataframe-in-python  , any help would be much much appreciated .

@emileymille - I can try it.

sure please help me out.

I have edited my question in this post, its not working for duplicates business name , its making it a single row , can you have a look?

@emileymille - Yes, it is in second part of my answer.

@emileymille - btw, I ty different libs for parse pdf and best is your solution - I try this

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
